# PactDslJsonBody is failing to create JSON object

Tags: testing, integration, pact, pact-jvm

@Pact(provider="Appointment_Provider",consumer = "Appointment_Consumer") 
    public PactFragment createFragmentAppointmentDetails (PactDslWithProvider builder) throws ParseException{

```
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>(); 
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json"); 


        return builder
                .given("GetAppoinment")
                .uponReceiving("Get Appointment information")
                .path("/getappointment")
                .query("apptId=11207")
                .method("GET")
                .willRespondWith()
                .headers(headers)
                .status(200)
                .body(new PactDslJsonBody()
                        .object("appointments")
                        .stringValue("type","Test \\u0026 Turn up")
                        .stringValue("apptId","11207")
                        .closeObject()
                        )
                .toFragment()
                ;
```

}

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke pact method
 at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.PactProviderRule.getPacts(PactProviderRule.java:269)
 at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.PactProviderRule$1.evaluate(PactProviderRule.java:145)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a dependency - can you post your dependencies?

Comment: @Nisha Could you please provide more context and maybe a better example that includes everything relative to Pact?  It does sounds like you're missing a dependency, how are you adding the Pact dependency to your project?  Can you show us the file?

Comment: These are two pact dependencies added<!-- Pact dependencies -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
   <artifactId>pact-jvm-consumer-junit_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.4</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
     <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
   <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-junit_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.4</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think I see it now.  You need to end `new PactDslJsonBody()` with `closeObject()` (so there's 2 in the end since you opened another object within it) since the JsonBody creates an object itself. It should look like this:

```
builder
    .given("GetAppoinment")
    .uponReceiving("Get Appointment information")
    .path("/getappointment")
    .query("apptId=11207")
    .method("GET")
    .willRespondWith()
    .headers(headers)
    .status(200)
    .body(
            new PactDslJsonBody() // This opens a root object
                .object("appointments") // creates a new object with in the root one
                    .stringValue("type","Test \\u0026 Turn up")
                    .stringValue("apptId","11207")
                .closeObject() // closes the child object
           .closeObject() // closes the root object
    )
    .toFragment();
```